# When is finalize() invoked during garbage collection?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, finalize

From :

Q11 of https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-management-interview-questions

**When an object becomes eligible for GC, the garbage collector has to run the finalize() on it; this method is guaranteed to run only once, thus the collector flags the object as finalized and gives it a rest until the next cycle.**

I have a few questions to ask:

- Is that statement correct?
- Is it during the marking phase, does the garbage collector invoke the finalize() method?
- Why does it give a rest until the next cycle?

P.S: I do understand that finalize() is finally deprecated in Java 9. Thanks to good soul who decided to make it so.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I forget how specific the Java spec is about finalize, so I don't know if it says exactly what phase the GC will invoke `finalize()`, but *"eligible for garbage collection"* is the important bit.  That's when an object can `finalize()`.

Comment: @markspace The spec ([JLS 12.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6)) doesn't say anything about phases. That's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it during the marking phase, does the garbage collector invoke the finalize() method?

Implementation dependent, but generally no. The finalizer is called by a background thread after GC completes.

Remember, GC may be a stop-the-world event, and should be as short as possible. Finalizer methods may be slow, so they should not be called during GC.

> Why does it give a rest until the next cycle?

At a high level (simplified), it operates as follows (see [JLS 12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) for terms):

- GC detect objects that are not *reachable*:

  - If object has a finalizer method, add it to the finalizer queue.
    The object is *finalizable*.
  - If the object is reachable from an *finalizable* object, leave it.
    The object is *finalizer-reachable*.
  - Otherwise reclaim memory now.
    The object was *unreachable*.
- Background Finalizer thread processes queued *finalizable* objects:

  - Invokes `finalize()` method.
    When method returns, the object is *finalized*.
- Since GC has already completed, *finalized* objects are "resting" until next GC cycle.
- On next GC cycle, objects with a finalizer method that is marked *finalized* is treated as *unreachable*, and memory will be reclaimed (assuming finalizer method didn't make the object *reachable* again).

Note that many GC cycles may occur while an object is *finalizable*, i.e. it may take a while for the Finalizer thread to process the object.

Comment: In practice, the implementation does not mark objects as “finalized” but rather marks objects having a non-trivial `finalize()` as “not finalized” at creation, to be unmarked when becoming *finalizable*. So the garbage collector does not need to differentiate between unreachable objects not having a finalizer and unreachable objects whose finalizer did already run. It’s important to keep in mind that by the time the `finalize()` method returns, the object may not be unreachable (it should, but the method may contain arbitrary code).